# Alternative to google analytics that runs on ASP.NET and doesn't use IIS logs?

Tags: asp.net, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I need a hit counter for my various pages, but I can't use google analytics (my client isn't ready for cloud computing) and I can't use anything that requires access to the IIS logs (the server administrator owns them and doesn't want to give them up)

What resources are there for user usage tracking for what is essentially a hosted ASP.NET account?

I'm running an ASP.NET application on IIS 6.  I've turned on health monitoring, but so far that is just creating log data with no analytics.

Comment: You mean that you look for something simple ? and that google analytic is "cloud computing" == difficult ?

Comment: @Arristos No, me and my client both enjoy excessive complexity.  This is due to a firewall with no outgoing ports open.  Can't see the clouds when you live in a bunker.

Comment: What sort of "hit counter" are you after? If its simply something like how many users could you not implement your own solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recently wrote up a list of (mostly) free GA alternatives.

http://regulargeek.com/2010/05/29/25-free-google-analytics-alternatives/

Many of these are cloud-based, but there are some that are completely hosted as well. I cannot recommend a particular solution, but the most popular self-hosted packages look like Grape Web Statistics (http://www.quate.net/grape), Open Web Analytics (http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) and Piwik (http://piwik.org/).

Comment: This certainly is the most comprehensive list I've seen to date.

Comment: Accepted, because this was the answer that convinced me that for my narrow technical requirements, there probably isn't an existing solution.  I plan to use one of these on my personal sites though, because it's too cool to pass up, thanks.

Comment: I am surprised that none of the self-hosted packages would work for you. I do know that they are not the simplest packages to setup and use.

Comment: I have used Piwik for personal sites, and it's great!

Comment: It is a government IT department. We seem to like constraints.

Answer (score 5):

You could use something that logged raw data to a database and then analyse this information.

Various alternatives to Google Analytics reviewed here:

http://sixrevisions.com/usabilityaccessibility/10-promising-free-web-analytics-tools/

Andy

Comment: None of these are in ASP.net most require PHP

Answer (score 5):

You could add an http module to the asp.net pipeline and write off values to a sql database if you're in a do-it-yourself mood.

Answer (score 2):

How much detail do you need?  If don't need all the extensive features of these listed, I'd just write something myself.

for example, at the bottom of your master page, put something like:

```
<webapp:MyPageCounter ID="counter" runat="server" />
```

and then define the MyPageCounter usercontrol to log the page requested, IP address, and headers.  then you'd have all the information to generate some reports from.

If you DO need more features, well, I think some shared hosting allow PHP apps. ;)

Comment: OP specifically requested ASP.net.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the PHP analytics tool Piwik under Phalanger, a tool which executes PHP on the CLR